# How to debug the loop in my Python hangman game

Tags: python

I am trying to create a hangman game but there is a problem. Whenever I run my code the `random.choice(words_to_guess)` chooses a word and when I write the word it has chosen and it's the correct word, it does not stop. It keeps going in loops.

What can I do to make stop the loop?

```
import random

lives = 10

def welcome(): 
    name = input("enter your name: ")
    print("hello " + name)
    print( name + " you will have this many(10) ")

def computer_role():
    words_to_guess = ["salad", "mood"]
    random.choice(words_to_guess)
    return random.choice(words_to_guess)
computer = computer_role()
def game_correct():
    user = input("enter a letter: ")
    while  user in computer:
        print(user)
        game_correct()

def game_wrong():
    for  user in computer_role():
            cal = lives -1
            return cal
    print("wrong word" + user + "this is how many lives you have left" + str(lives))


welcome()
computer_role()
game_correct()
game_wrong()
```

I have tried to use `break` under where `game_correct()` is but there seems that dose not wan work as well. also I have tried `exit()` but that does not also work.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: `welcome`, `computer_role`, `game_correct` and `game_wrong` are executed in that order independently of whether the input is correct or wrong. Also `computer_role()` is going to return a string, but you are not assigning that string to anything in that line (you do it before, but I'm not sure why do you want to call that function again).

Comment: `while  user in computer:` should be `if user in computer:`

Comment: `game_correct` is a recursive function. Is that your intention?

Comment: Every time you call `computer_role()` it picks a different random word. So when you call `game_wrong()`, it will compare with a different one than `game_correct()` compared with. You should just call it once at the beginning of the game, then everything else should compare with `computer`.

Answer (score 1):

If you guess a correct letter the while loop will run forever as it never changes the variable called user. Instead of using a while loop, you should be using an if.

```py
def game_correct():
    user = input("enter a letter: ")
    if user in computer:
        print("Correct guess")
```

Should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm aware that this won't be enough to make the game usable but it solves their specific issue. I'm new to answering on SO but I assume I should let them solve the problem of making the game themselves.